# If $\lambda$ is the maximal weight of $V$ and $\mu$ is the maximal weight of $W$, then $\lambda+\mu$ is the maximal weight of $V\otimes W$.

Tags: solution-verification, representation-theory, lie-algebras, tensor-products

> Let $\mathfrak g$ be a finite-dimensional semisimple lie algebra, and let $Q^+$ be the set of linear combinations of simple roots with coefficients in $\mathbb Z_{\geq 0}$. Suppose that $V$ and $W$ are both finite-dimensional weight modules (i.e, both are written as a direct sum of weight spaces) such that all weights $\nu$ of $V$ satisfy $\nu \leq \lambda$, and all weights $\nu$ of $W$ satisfy $\nu \leq \mu$. Let us denote weight spaces of $V$ and $W$ by the notation $V_\nu$ and $W_\nu$ for weights $\nu$ in each of these modules. Is it true that $V\otimes W$ is a weight module such that its weights $\nu$ satisfy $\nu \leq \lambda + \mu?$

The module $V\otimes W$ will be a weight module since it is finite-dimensional. It is clear  $V_\lambda' \otimes W_\mu' \subseteq (V\otimes W)_{\mu'+\lambda'}$ for any weight $\lambda'$ in $V$ and any weight $\mu'$ in $W$. Conversely, any weight vector of $V\otimes W$ of weight $\nu$ is written as a linear combination of vectors of the form $v\otimes w$ with $v\in V, w \in W$. Since weights spaces are linearly independent, then all of the summands of the form $v\otimes w$ have weight $\nu$. However, $v$ has weight $\lambda'$ and $w$ has weight $\lambda'$, whence $\nu = \lambda' + \mu'$. This shows that the weights of $V\otimes W$ are of the form $\lambda'+\mu'$ for some weight $\lambda'$ of $V$ and $\mu'$ of $W$.

In particular, it is clear that $\lambda+\mu$ is weight of $V\otimes W$. If $\gamma=\lambda'+\mu'$ is a weight of $V\otimes W$ such that $\lambda+\mu \leq \gamma$, then $Q^+\ni \gamma - (\mu + \lambda) = (\mu' - \mu) + (\lambda' - \lambda)$, which is a contradiction since both $\mu'- \mu$ and $\lambda'  - \lambda$ do not lie in $Q^+$ by the fact that $\lambda$ and $\mu$ are maximal weights.

**Edit**: As pointed out in the comments, indeed $\mu'-\mu, \lambda'-\lambda\not \in Q^+$ can still imply that $(\mu'-\mu)+(\lambda'-\lambda)\in Q^+$. Is there a way I can fix this proof? Or is there any obvious counterexample for this statement?

Comment: I don't think your contradiction is solid: $a+b \in Q^+$ is possible without either $a\in Q^+$ or $b\in Q^+$.

Comment: @Callum. You are right. The conclusion would only hold if $a,b$ have all negative integer coefficients, but that's not what is meant by $a,b\not\in Q^+$.

Comment: You can show easily that if $a \leq A$ and $b \leq B$ then $a + b \leq A + B$. Together with your first observation that any weight of $V \otimes W$ is of the form $a + b$ for some weight $a$ of $V$ and $b$ of $W$, doesn't this conclude the argument?